# Display labels Horizontally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

What i want is to display the 2 labels Horizontally, but what i get is the label gets displayed in a vertical way. I want to change it in a way it displays horizontally (side ways). how could i customize it ?

```
  items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'form',
                    items: [{
                        xtype:'label',
                        text: "label 1"
                     },
                     {
                          xtype:'label',
                         text: "Label 2"
                     }

                     ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'column',
    items: [
        {
            xtype:'label',
            text: "label 1",
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            xtype:'label',
            text: "Label 2",
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
```